# Javascript equivalent of PHP's list()

Tags: php, javascript, list, phpjs

Really like that function.

```
$matches = array('12', 'watt');
list($value, $unit) = $matches;
```

Is there a Javascript equivalent of that?

Comment: What's wrong with a standard approach `var value = matches[0]; var unit = matches[1]; `

Comment: Well, that's not very concise, is it?

Comment: I never felt `list()` to be useful and the above just yells object to me `var power = { 'unit': 'watt', 'amount': 12 }`

Comment: It's very ugly and long. I think list() makes code more readable.

Comment: @Gordon: Not many functions returns objects, like ''.match()

Comment: @Znarkus: I'd still create a ValueObject out of the array, but feel free to do it differently :)

Comment: @Gordon: list(power.unit, power.amount) = weirdStringToParse.match(massiveRegEx)

Comment: @Znarkus var getPowerFromWeirdString = function(weirdString) {var power = weirdString.match(massiveRegEx); return {'unit': power[0], 'amount': power[1] }; };

Comment: Haha Gordon, you could wrap my solution in a function also :)

Comment: @Tchalvak adding external dependencies is never more coincise.

Comment: Here's another way of accomplishing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9853132/675007

Comment: PHP's `list()` is handy if you want to swap variable values without the need of a temporary variable: `list($b, $a) = array($a, $b);`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is, in 'newer' versions of Javascript: [Destructuring assignment - Javascript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment). It's probably only supported in Mozilla-based browsers, and maybe in Rhino.

```
var a = 1;  
var b = 3;  

[a, b] = [b, a];
```

EDIT: <del>actually it wouldn't surprise me if the V8 Javascript library (and thus Chrome) supports this. But don't count on it either</del> 
Now [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) in all modern browsers(**except IE**, of course).

Comment: Neat! I really like all the cool stuff they've put into the new versions of Javascript! Just feels like we wont be able to use them for ages..

Comment: Year 2015 and still unsupported by V8.

Comment: Firefox supports it since version 2 back in 2006. It's still not supported by V8/Chrome in 2015. Chrome is the new IE.

Comment: Be careful using this still in 2018; IE never supported it, and many people still use it. Useful for judging compatibility: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Reporting from 2019 March. This is working in Chrome 72 (64-bit).

Answer (score 20):

try this:

```
matches = ['12', 'watt'];
[value, unit] = matches;
```

Answer (score 19):

ES6 does support this directly now via [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
const matches = ['12', 'watt'];
const [value, unit] = matches;
```

Comment: As of mid-2019 this is the best answer. The accepted answer will throw "[variable] is not defined (no-undef)" warnings in many linters. This corrects for that.

Note that you can also do array deconstructing in for...of loops

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution for using List/Explode on Javascript. 
[Fiddle Working Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HfnDE/1/)

First the implementation :

```
var dateMonth = "04/15";
dateMonth.split("/").list("month","day", "year");
month == "04";
day == "15";
year == null;
```

It also allows for scoping the new generated variables :

```
var scoped = (function()
{ 
    var dateMonth = "07/24/2013"; 
    dateMonth.split("/").list("month","day", "year", this);
    this.month == "07";
    this.day == "24";
    this.year == "2013";
})();
```

This was accomplished by modifying an the Array prototype.

```
Array.prototype.list = function()
{
    var 
        limit = this.length,
        orphans = arguments.length - limit,
        scope = orphans > 0  && typeof(arguments[arguments.length-1]) != "string" ? arguments[arguments.length-1] : window 
    ;

    while(limit--) scope[arguments[limit]] = this[limit];

    if(scope != window) orphans--;

    if(orphans > 0)
    {
        orphans += this.length;
        while(orphans-- > this.length) scope[arguments[orphans]] = null;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm sticking with my solution. If you try something like :

matches = ['12', 'watt'];
[value, unit] = matches; 

Or 
function () {
var [year, month] = $(this).val().split("/");

In Chrome, it will throw an error : 
"ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: Using `window` as a default object is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Bergi he only defaults to it. You can provide an object as the last parameter and it will use that.

Comment: @lac_dev love this little script, works perfectly for me. Very nice that you account for labels that exceed the data

Answer (score 2):

There is a experimental implementation of `list()` by [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org) here:
https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/_experimental/array/list.js

Comment: The second link in this post is dead (*404 - This is not the web page you are looking for*).

Answer (score 2):

[CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) offers destructuring assignment with the syntax:

```
[a, b] = someFunctionReturningAnArray()
```

This is pretty much identical to the feature offered in very new JavaScript versions. However, CoffeeScript produces compiled JS that is compatible even with IE6's JavaScript engine, and therefore it's a good option if compatibility is vital.

Answer (score 1):

Since most JavaScript implementations don't yet support that feature, you could simply do it in a more JavaScript-like fashion:

```js
function list(){
    var args = arguments;
    return function(array){
        var obj = {};
        for(i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            obj[args[i]] = array[i];
        }
        return obj;
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
var array = ['GET', '/users', 'UserController'];
var obj = {};

obj = list('method', 'route', 'controller')(array);

console.log(obj.method);        // "GET"
console.log(obj.route);         // "/users"
console.log(obj.controller);    // "UserController"
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/804fem98/)

---

An alternative is to add a list-method to Array.prototype (even I wouldn't recommend it):

```js
Array.prototype.list = function(){
    var i, obj = {};
    for(i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        obj[arguments[i]] = this[i];
    }
    // if you do this, you pass to the dark side `,:,´
    this.props = obj;
    return obj;
};
```

Example:

```js
/**
 * Example 1: use Array.prototype.props
 */

var array = ['GET', '/users', 'UserController'];
array.list('method', 'route', 'controller');

console.log(array.props.method);        // "GET"
console.log(array.props.route);         // "/users"
console.log(array.props.controller);    // "UserController"

/**
 * Example 2: use the return value
 */

var array = ['GET', '/users', 'UserController'];
var props = array.list('method', 'route', 'controller');

console.log(props.method);      // "GET"
console.log(props.route);       // "/users"
console.log(props.controller);  // "UserController"
```

[Check the fiddle for that one](http://jsfiddle.net/d5h3gta9/)

Answer (score 0):

This is my hack at it; as short as I could get it without writing a function to do it. Gotta be careful of the scope of "this" though:

```
list = ["a","b","c"];
vals = [1,2,3];
for(var i in vals)this[list[i]]=vals[i];
console.log(a,b,c);
```

Good enough for a laugh. I still assign each variable one at a time:

```
a=vals[0];
b=vals[1];
c=vals[2];
```

It's much shorter this way. Besides, if you've got a bunch of variables they should probably be kept in the array, or even better they should be properties of a closure, instead of declaring them all separately.

Answer (score -2):

```
function list(fn,array){
    if(fn.length && array.length){
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            var applyArray = [];
            for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
                fn[j] = array[i][j];
                applyArray.push(fn[j]);
            }
        fn.apply(this,applyArray);
       }
   }
}
```

Example:

```
//array array mixture for composure
var arrayMixture = [ ["coffee","sugar","milk"], ["tea","sugar","honey"] ];
//call our function


list(function(treat,addin,addin2){
    console.log("I like "+treat+" with " + addin + " and " + addin2);
},arrayMixture);


//output:
//I like coffee with sugar and milk
//I like tea with sugar and honey
```