# JavaScript construct equivalent to PHP's list()?

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript equivalent of PHP's list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954426/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-list)

In PHP you can do assignment like this:

```
list($b,$c,$d) = array("A","B","C");
```

Is there anything like that in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People seem to hate the with() construct in javascript, but anyway...

```
function f(){return {a:1, b:2};}
with(f()) {
    alert(a);//1
}


// or
function combine(propertyNames, values) {
    var o = {};
    for (var i=0; i<propertyNames.length; i++) {
        o[propertyNames[i]] = values[i];
    }
    return o;
}

with (combine(['a', 'b'], [1, 2])) {
    alert(b);//2
}
```

Comment: Which version of JS is this?  Does IE7 support it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible since [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_javascript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29)

You can do:

```
function f() {  
  return [1, 2];  
}  

[a, b] = f();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, need to support IE7 :(

Comment: I don't believe this works in Opera. Does anyone know if this works at all in `strict mode`?

Comment: In that case you'll have to avoid that feature :(

Comment: @btleffler: You can check it on that page: http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-1.7.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that was introduced in JavaScript 1.7. Which means you can't really use it yet in the majority of browsers.

```
[a,b] = [14,15];
// or
[a,b] = [b,a];
// or
[a,b] = someFuncThatReturnsArray();
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#section_20) for more details.

Comment: Really bummer, I need to support IE7.