# using division operator (/) on strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I realized that in javascript all 101/100, "101"/100, 101/"100" and "101"/"100" result in 1.01 (checked on Chrome, FF and IE11). But I cannot find a piece of documentation regarding this behaviour.

Therefore my question is if it is (cross-browser) safe to use this feature, and if it is a good practice to do so (or rather to use parseInt before division if the variable can be a string)?

Comment: That's a specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Yes, there is. That isn't it. [This is](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), or more accurately [this PDF](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf).

Comment: Living specification: [evaluation of a MultiplicativeExpression](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), [ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Therefore my question is if it is (cross-browser) safe to use this feature...

It depends on your definition of "safe." With the division operator, yes, it's **specified** behavior: Each operand is converted (implicitly coerced) to a number, and then numeric division is done.

But beware of generalizing this too far. You'll be okay with `/`, `*`, and `-` but it will bite you on `+`, because if either operand to `+` is a string, `+` does string concatenation, not addition.

Another way that it may or may not be "safe" depending on your point of view is the implicit coercion: It uses the browser's JavaScript engine's rules for converting strings to numbers. Some older browsers went beyond the specification (which they were allowed to in the past) and treated numbers starting with a `0` as *octal* (base 8) rather than decimal. Naturally, end users who type in, say, "0123" as a number probably mean the number 123, not the number 83 (`123` in octal = `83` decimal). JavaScript engines are no longer allowed to do that, but some older ones do.

In general, it's probably best to explicitly coerce or convert those operands. Your choices for doing so:

- The unary `+` operator:  `value = +value` will coerce the string to a number using the JavaScript engine's standard rules for that. Any non-digits in the string (other than the `e` for scientific notation) make the result `NaN`. Also, `+""` is `0`, which may not be intuitive.
- The `Number` function: `value = Number(value)`. Does the same thing as `+`.
- The `parseInt` function, usually with a radix (number base): `value = parseInt(value, 10)`. The downside here is that `parseInt` converts any number it finds at the beginning of the string but **ignores** non-digits later in the string, so `parseInt("100asdf", 10)` is `100`, not `NaN`. As the name implies, `parseInt` parses only a whole number.
- The `parseFloat` function: `value = parseFloat(value)`. Allows fractional values, and always works in decimal (never octal or hex). Does the same thing `parseInt` does with garbage at the end of the string, `parseFloat("123.34alksdjf")` is `123.34`.

So, pick your tool to suit your use case. :-)

Comment: `"10" * 1` and `"10"/1` can also be used for type casting, is there any disadvantage of using them for this purpose

Comment: @Tushar: Multiplication and division are expensive, so using `*1` or `/1` is relying on the JavaScript engine to optimize the actual operation out and just do the coercion. I'm not entirely sure it can even do that (what with the vagaries of IEEE-754 math). Of course, 99.999% of the time, performance doesn't matter, and modern systems offload floating point to the chip. But the `+` idiom is very deeply ingrained in JavaScript culture and doesn't have that issue, so... (Another one you see often is `value = value|0`.)

Answer (score 6):

When you use `/` on strings, the strings are implicitly converted to numbers and then division operation is performed.

This may work in all browsers, but it's always good practice to convert to number explicitly using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` or other method.

```
parseInt("101", 10) / 100
```

Or

```
parseFloat("101") / 100
```

[ECMAScript Specifications for Division Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.2)

Comment: it's a good answer, but the "Applying the / Operator" section in the document You've linked still doesn't regard strings.

Comment: @Arsen: True (it's also the old spec), http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation would be the bit that talks about the implicit coercion in the current spec. (But still a good answer, as you said; has my vote.)

Answer (score 0):

**Type coercion** is at play here. Quoting @Barmar's answer from [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)

> Type coercion means that when the operands of an operator are of different types, one of them will be converted to an "equivalent" value of the other operand's type.

The reason for your observation is valid for other operations too -

```
1 + "2" will give you "12"
1 - "2" will give you -1
```

(because "-" operation on strings is not defined like division")

In the case "101/100" the operation "/" will decide the coercion, since there is no operation defined on strings with that operator "/", but is there for "numbers".

Using it is safe (at least in modern browsers) as long as you are clear how type coercion will play out in your operation.

Comment: "Type coercion means that when the operands of an operator are **different types**" - it doesn't apply to the "101" / "100" = 1.01 case thou.

Comment: @Arsen In that case the operation "/" will decide the coercion, since there is no operation defined on strings with that operator "/".