# simple arrays and conditions javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So im a newbie and I need some basic help. I wanna make a program that checks whether room is free or taken. I dont know if i can make just a variable with all free rooms or should i do this the other way. I'm kinda stuck on solving the problem.

```
function action() {
    var room = document.getElementById('text');
    var free = [1, 2, 3];
    if (room.value == free) {
        alert('Hello');
    } else {
        alert('Taken');
    }
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    action();
}
```

I wanna ask if is it possible to just compare variable i enter to other variable with list of free rooms if not, how to make this work then?

Comment: What about storing whether a room is free as an attribute `data-*` on the element?

Comment: Input data is not clear. Is the user supposed to introduce the room number inside a text field?

Comment: `free.indexOf(room.value) > -1`

Comment: User is introducing number of room in the text field

Comment: Something like this maybe http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/982yq3zf/

Answer (score 2):

You can't just compare your number with an array. You need to check if your number is in the array:

```
if (free.indexOf(room.value) > -1)
```

Also, assuming you're using a text field, you'll need to convert `room.value` to a Number (instead of String) before checking:

```
if (free.indexOf(+room.value) > -1)
```

You can learn more about [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

The line `if (room.value == free)` compares a **string** (the value) with an **array**. That won't usually be true.

To find a value in an array, you use `Array#indexOf`. It does strict comparison, so since your values in the array are numbers, you have to make sure that your value is a number as well.

So

```
if (free.indexOf(+room.value) != -1) {
    // Yes it's there
}
```

The unary `+` is one way to convert strings to numbers. Another is `parseInt`, which lets you specify a radix (number base):

```
if (free.indexOf(parseInt(room.value, 10)) != -1) {
    // Yes it's there
}
```

You have other options as well; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203164/157247) lists the various options and the pros and cons of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Going further, you can remove the room number taken from the list of free rooms and push them into list of rooms already taken.

```js
function action() {
  var isRoomAvailable = false;
  var room = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var freeRoom = [1, 2, 3]; // 4-10 are taken rooms.
  var takenRooms = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  for (var i = 0; i < freeRoom.length; i++) {
    if (room == freeRoom[i]) {
      alert('Hello, You can take room '+room);
      isRoomAvailable = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  if (!isRoomAvailable) alert("Sorry, Room number " + room + " is taken");
}



document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  action()
}
```

```html
Enter Room number(1-10):
<input type="text" id="text" />

<button id="button">Search Room</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps use a 0 and 1 system for storing whether a room is taken. So 0 is for taken and 1 is for free or vice versa depending on your liking. So all it would have to do is test for whether in the array, the room's value is 0 or 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I happen to like this idea as an alternate solution, so +1. :)

Comment: Or you can use -1 and 1 if you want it to be easily toggled as -1^2 is 1 and 1*-1 is -1 :)