# In JavaScript, why would my "<" and ">" comparisons be reversed?

Tags: javascript

When I run this code through an html page in chrome, and put in, for example, number1 = 1000 and number2 gets 2000, it alerts 1000 is bigger. Why?

```
var number1 = prompt("Pick a number");
var number2 = prompt("Pick another number");

if (number1 < number2) {
    alert(number1 + "is bigger!");
} else if (number2 < number1) {
    alert(number2 + "is bigger!");
} else if (number1 == number2) {
    alert(number1 + "is equal to" + number2)
}
```

Comment: You're alerting the wrong messages `x < y` means `x is less than y`

Comment: @PaulS. That's *half* the problem, indeed. :-)

Comment: I apologize, I had temporarily reversed the comparison symbols. They were originally: 

var number1 = prompt("Pick a number");
var number2 = prompt("Pick another number");

if (number1 > number2) {
 alert(number1 + "is bigger!");
} else if (number2 > number1) {
 alert(number2 + "is bigger!");
} else if (number1 == number2) {
 alert(number1 + "is equal to" + number2)
}

... and it was still alerting backwards.

Comment: To check if number1 is bigger than number2 you need to wright it like this: number1 > number2

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems above:

1. Your messages are backward
2. You're comparing **strings**, not numbers

You want to convert the result of `prompt` to number, and also correct which messages you're displaying.

You have several options for converting strings to numbers; I list your options and their plusses and minuses [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203164/157247).

If you only fix #1 and not #2, you'll end up saying that `"20"` is less than `"3"`, because comparing strings with `<` compares them *lexigraphically*, and `"2"` comes before `"3"` (the `"0"` in `"20"` never even gets looked at).