# JS add operation return char+char, not int+int

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("input[class$='m_value']").keyup(function() {

        var val1 = $('#v1').val();
        var val2 = $('#v2').val();
        var val3 = $('#v3').val();

        var total = val1+val2+val3;

        $( "#total" ).val( total );
    });
});
```

if #v1= 1  #v2=5

I will get  15 , not 6

why the code just char+char...?  this not int+int.

Comment: Input values are always strings, you've to convert them to numbers before doing the math. Automatic type coersion doesn't do it for you, since `+` is used to concatenate strings too.

Comment: How to convert?  html or js setting???

Comment: Sky, google "convert string to number javascript" and you'll find many answers :)

Comment: Use `parseInt()` [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using strings. The return value of `val` when used on `input` elements is *always* a string. (On `select` elements with `multiple`, it can be `null` or an array; if you call it on a jQuery set that has no elements in it at all, it will be `undefined`).

So first, turn your values into numbers, using the unary `+`, or `parseInt`, or `parseFloat`, or `Number`.

Example using unary `+` (changes on first three lines):

```
var val1 = +$('#v1').val();
var val2 = +$('#v2').val();
var val3 = +$('#v3').val();

var total = val1+val2+val3;

$( "#total" ).val( total ); // Implicit conversion to string here
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203164/157247) lists various ways to convert to number and their various idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much Crowder.

Comment: One other exception regarding jQuery `val()` is that it can return array too

Comment: @A.Wolff: I Did Not Know That! Wow. I would have said I knew jQuery pretty darned well by now. Just goes to show, there's always something to learn. Fixed, and **many** thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, that makes two. I thought `val()` returns a singular value. And in the case of an element collection from the preceding selector, the first elements value

Comment: @AmmarCSE: It's in the answer above: A `select` element with the `multiple` attribute. You're right that when used as a getter, `val` always only works with the *first* element in the set (like the other getters). But if that element  is a `select` with `multiple`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Ha! I literally just skimmed through that :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `val()` function reads everything as text. If the input to those three elements are always integers you can just convert the values to integers using `parseInt`.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[class$='m_value']").keyup(function() {

    var val1 = parseInt($('#v1').val());
    var val2 = parseInt($('#v2').val());
    var val3 = parseInt($('#v3').val());

    var total = val1+val2+val3;

    $( "#total" ).val( total );
    });
});
```

Here is the  JavaScript reference on [ParseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).