# function addition javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have a math program that randomly generates 2 numbers and displays them in 2 places (eg. num1 and num2) I have created the if statement that will show correct or incorrect depending on user input. I believe the error is in the if else statement

```js
function check() {
var txt = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
if(txt=n1+n2){hideshow(document.getElementById('correct'));}
else{hideshow(document.getElementById('incorrect'));}
}
```

For anyone curious, here is all my code:

```js
function num1() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = x;
}
function num2() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = x;
}
function check() {
var txt = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
if(txt=n1+n2){hideshow(document.getElementById('correct'));}
else{hideshow(document.getElementById('incorrect'));}
}
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
if (which.style.display=="block")
which.style.display="none"
else
which.style.display="block"
}
```

```css
 p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="http://hokuco.com/style.css">
<body onload ="num1();num2();hideshow(document.getElementById('correct'));hideshow(document.getElementById('incorrect'));">
<div id ="headline">
<pre><p id="num1" name ="qty"></p> + <p id="num2"name ="qty"></p></pre>
<textarea id ="textarea"></textarea></br>
<button onclick="check();">check</button>
<button onclick="num1();num2();hide(document.getElementById('correct'));hide(document.getElementById('incorrect'));">new</button>
<div id="correct" style="font:24px bold; display: block">Good job!</div>
<div id="incorrect" style="font:24px bold; display: block">Incorrect</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(txt=n1+n2)`, no further questions?

Comment: He means == instead of just =. = is assignment == is compare

Comment: ^^ + `value` and `innerHTML` give you strings, hence concatenating strings probably gives you unexpected results. Convert them to numbers before doing any math.

Comment: still don't get what u mean I already tried 1 2 3 equals and didn't work

Comment: Also, `document.getElementById` is not worth of checking, it has been around for a while. Did you mean to check, if `which` exists?

Comment: Please properly format your code in the future.

Comment: how do u convert string to number?

Comment: Please consult [JavaScript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `innerHtml` would retrieve a string not a number, you'll have to parse it.

In addition, the `if(txt=n1+n2)` won't check if the first nuber equals the second, it will add the first number to the second, and the result will always be true unliss if the result of addition where false or null or undefined. To check if the first one equals the second one, you'll need to use `==`.

```
function check() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
    n1=parseInt(n1);
    n2=parseInt(n2);
    if(txt==n1+n2){hideshow(document.getElementById('correct'));}
    else{hideshow(document.getElementById('incorrect'));}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The `value` of an `input` and the `innerHTML` of an element are always **strings**
2. `=` is for assignment, not comparison

So your

```
if (txt=n1+n2)
```

will

1. Assign the result of tacking the `n2` string onto the end of the `n1` string to `txt`
2. Go into the body of the `if` if the resulting string isn't completely blank

To do *addition*, you need to convert to number. I go into some detail about how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203164/157247). To do *comparison*, use `==` or `===`. It doesn't matter which you use if the operands are of the same type. If they aren't, `==` will try to coerce them for the purposes of comparison (sometimes in surprising ways), `===` will not (it'll say they're not equal if they're of different types).

Answer (score 0):

```
function check() {
var txt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("textarea").value);
var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML);
var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML);
alert(txt==n1+n2);
if(txt==n1+n2){hideshow(document.getElementById('correct'));}
else{hideshow(document.getElementById('incorrect'));}
}
```

You were missing ==, not =.
And txt, n1, n2 were strings not numbers. so you had to parseFloat them