# always choose else condition in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to give a condition if value of id=type_investor is 1 or 6 to send mail using different controller.

here is my full code :

```
function (isConfirm) {
            if (!isConfirm) return;
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/approve-depositwithdraw")}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id: fund_id,key: refdc_data},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/approve-tostatement")}}",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {id: fund_id},
                            dataType: "html"});

                            if ($('#type_investor').val == 1){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/sendmail-deposit")}}",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "html"});
                            }else{
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/sendmail-withdraw")}}",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "html"}); 
                            }

                    swal("Approved!", "It was succesfully Approved!", "success");
                    $('#refdc').val('');
                    window.location.href = "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/")}}";
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    swal("Error Approved!", "Please try again", "error");
                    window.location.href = "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/")}}";
                }
            });
```

And I think, maybe the point of problem is in this code

```
if ($('#type_investor').val == 1){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/sendmail-deposit")}}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"});
}else{
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/sendmail-withdraw")}}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"}); 
}
```

because if condition value of `id="type_investor"` is `1` , it use controller in **else** condition.
it always using **else** condition. I dont know where is actually my problem.

Comment: Try `$('#type_investor').val()`

Comment: `$('#type_investor').val` is a function, which is never falsy. You want the *return value* of that function to be tested.

Comment: First what is the value of `$('#type_investor').val()` ?. Try to use `alert` or `console.log` to see what is the return value.

Comment: @TrafalgarDLaw: Rather than stumbling about in the dark with an `alert` or `console.log` torch, turn on the lights using the debugger.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you can also use debugger.

Comment: I found my solution, after use debugger, i used .text() . so the code is like this if ($('#type_investor').text == 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution, after use debugger, i used .text() . so the code is like this

```
if ($('#type_investor').text == 1){
$.ajax({
    url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/sendmail-deposit")}}",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"});
}else{
$.ajax({
    url: "{{URL::to("cpanel/deposit-withdraw-list/sendmail-withdraw")}}",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`val` is a function, you have to *call* it:

```
if ($('#type_investor').val() == 1){
// ------------------------^^
```

---

Note that you're relying on implicit conversion there, as `val` always returns a string (unless the jQuery set is empty, then it returns `undefined`). FWIW, you can find your various options for implicitly or explicitly converting the string to a number in [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203164/157247).

Comment: I add () like that, and that doesn't work. I still get ELSE condition

Comment: @arbong: Then the `id="type_investor"` element doesn't exist, or doesn't have the value `"1"`.

Comment: this value is exist and have value = "1"

Comment: @arbong if it is really exist then this is the right one.

Comment: @arbong: No, it doesn't. If it did, `$('#type_investor').val() == 1` would be `true`. [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Could you have more than one `id="type_investor"` elements? If so, usually the first one is picked (though since having multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid, that's not guaranteed and relies on the browser's underlying `getElementById` behavior).

Comment: I used ctrl+f to find id="type_investor" . and there is only one in that page. So, this make me confuse why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$('#type_investor').val` which returns the value `undefined`

val is a function not property

you should call it as

```
$('#type_investor').val();
```

Comment: how the condition that if the value of id="type_investor" is 1, and if the other is 6 then ....

Comment: `$('#type_investor').val() == 1 || $('#type_investor').val() == 6`