# split string and store it in 3 variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split ZIN.2.1 into 3 variables
var1=zin
var2=zin.2
var3=zin.2.1

So far i have tried

```
var text = "zin.2.1";
var splitted = text.split(".");
console.log(splitted);
console.log(splitted[0]);

</script>
```

output: ["zin", "2", "1"]
"zin"

Is there anything i can try to achieve. I am new to js

Comment: `var2=zin.1` not `var2=zin.2`?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954426/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-list

Comment: @dfsq yes it is zin.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
function mySplit(text) {

  var splitted = text.split("."), arr = [];

  arr.push(splitted[0]);
  arr.push(splitted[0] + '.'+ splitted[2]);
  arr.push(text);

 return arr;

}
```

var text = "zin.2.1";

console.log(mySplit(text));

Output:

```
["zin", "zin.1", "zin.2.1"]
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HlzLPNpA8yWgra6kxVmo?p=preview)

Comment: I am having hard time storing the array value.
var first = arr[0];
var second= arr[1];
"ReferenceError: arr is not defined
Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to loop through your array and build up a string of each value into a new array:

```js
var text = "zin.2.1";
var splitted = text.split(".");

// build this string up
var s = "";

var splitted2 = splitted.map(function(v) {

    // don't add a . for the first entry
    if(s.length > 0) {
        s += '.';
    }

    s += v;

    // returning s will set it as the next value in the new array
    return s;
});

console.log(splitted2);
```