# $$key php equivalent in node.js

Tags: php, node.js, foreach

I have an array and I am using foreach loop to iterate through that array and I want each key in that array to be converted in to a varible. like we do in PHP.
for example:

```
foreach (['browser_id', 'device_id', 'os_id', 'event', ] as $var) {
            $$var = $request->$var ?? Session::put($var) ?? "";
        }
```

How to do exactly this in Node.js?
I have this array

```
var paramss = ['browser_id', 'device_id', 'os_id', 'event', 'eventName', 'billingstatus', 'step'];
```

I want to loop these using foreach and convert each of these keys in to a varible. like browser_id,device_id etc will be a varible.Please help

I have tried this:

```
paramss.forEach(element => {
  var element = req.query[element] ? req.query[element] : '';
console.log(element) });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to variable name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: no it doesn't, I am not able use window or eval

Comment: How about just [array destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957000/231316)?

Answer (score 0):

[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object is not available in [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) however you can use [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

```
global["foo"] = 'bar'
```

So you can access it using `foo` variable

```
console.log(foo) // bar
```

so in your case you can do this

```
paramss.forEach(element => {
  global[element] = req.query[element] ? req.query[element] : '';
})
```

then you can get the element as variable defined

Comment: it is not working. can you share any fiddle? Thanks a lot